# Finding an example of $\lim_{x\to b} |f(x)|=1$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to find an example of function $f(x)$ where $\lim_{x\to b} |f(x)|=1$ and $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)\neq-1$ and $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)\neq1$ (where $b\in \mathbb{R}$).

I tried to think of some sort of a function of type $f(x)=(-1)^x$ that depends of $b$ but it looks like to does not leads to anything. Which example I can use?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. $\lim_{x\to b} f(x)$ cannot be both $-1$ and $1$.

Comment: Maybe you mean the limit from above/below? Then you can use a variation of the Heaviside function

Comment: $f(x)=-1 for $x<b$ and 1 for $x\ge b$

Comment: Sorry! I have meant $\neq$. I'll edit the question.

Comment: $f(x) = sgn[\sin(\frac{1}{x-b})]$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You can define $f$ to be constant on the rationals and irrationals respectively but with different constants on each respective set.

Answer (score 2):

Take
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
+1 \quad & x\geq b \\
-1 & x<b.
\end{cases}$$